# ElasticSearch, Logstash, MySQL: how do I speed up a large import?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to import a large (~30M row) MySQL database to ElasticSearch. Cool cool, there's a `logstash` tool that looks like it's built for this sort of thing; its JDBC plugin will let me connect right to the database and slurp up the rows real fast.

However! When I try it, it bombs with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Okay. It's probably trying to batch up too many rows or something. So I add `jdbc_fetch_size => 1000` to my configuration. No dice, still out of memory. Okay, maybe that option doesn't work, or doesn't do what I think?

So I try adding `jdbc_paging_enabled => true` and `jdbc_page_size => 10000` to my config. Success! It starts adding rows in batches of 10k to my index.

But it slows down. At first I'm running 100k rows/minute; by the time I'm at 2M rows, however, I'm at maybe a tenth of that. And no surprise; I'm pretty sure this is using LIMIT and OFFSET, and using huge OFFSETs in queries is real slow, so I'm dealing with an O(n^2) kind of thing here.

I'd really like to just run the whole big query and let the cursor iterate over the resultset, but it looks like that isn't working for some reason. If I had more control over the query, I could change the LIMIT/OFFSET thing out for an `WHERE id BETWEEN val1 AND val2` kind of thing, but I can't see where I could get in to do that.

Any suggestions on how I can not crash, but still run at a reasonable speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay! After searching the issues for the logstash-input-jdbc github page for "Memory" I found [this revelation](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/103#issuecomment-281593127):

> It seems that an additional parameter `?useCursorFetch=true` needs to be added to the connection string of mysql 5.x.

It turns out that the MySQL JDBC client does not use a cursor for fetching rows by default because of some reason, and the logstash client doesn't warn you that it's not able to use a cursor to iterate over the resultset even though you've set a `jdbc_fetch_size` because of some other reason.

The obvious way to know about this, of course, would have been to have carefully read [the MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) which does mention that cursors are off by default, though not why.

Anyhow, I added `useCursorFetch=true` to the connection string, kicked `jdbc_query_paging` to the curb, and imported 26M rows into my index in 2.5 hours, on an aging Macbook Pro with 8G memory.

Thanks to github user [axhiao](https://github.com/axhiao) for the helpful comment!

Comment: Dear Nate, I am also facing similar problem. Can you share your Logstash conf file, I tried all but it's not working at all. Thanks